# How to define different name for struct with generics

Tags: swift, generics

If I have a struct defined as

`struct S<T> {}`

How do I create a specific name for `S<Int>`? Something like:

`let I = S<Int>`

So that I can use `I` anywhere I'd use `S<Int>`, like for static functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `typealias` should do the trick:

```
typealias WithInt = S<Int>
```